# Calling a previous function in a new function

Tags: python, function, edx

I'm doing the CS1301xII course through edX and I'm being asked to calculate Pokemon damage by using one function to calculate the modifier, which I need to call another for the calculation.

There are 9 parameters:
STAB, Type, Critical, Other, Random, Level, Attack, Defense, and Base.

My first function calculates a modifier used in the damage calculation. This is (STAB * Type * Critical * Other * Random) for reference.

```
def calculate_modifier(s, t, c, o, r):
   mod = s * t * c * o * r
```

My second function is to calculate overall damage. This is (((2 * Level + 10) / 250) * (Attack / Defense) * Base + 2) for reference.

```
def calculate_damage(l, a, d, b):
  dam = (((2 * l + 10) / 250) * (a / d) * b + 2)
```

How do I go about calling the calculate_modifier function within my calculate_damage function? Do I list all 9 of the parameters? Really struggling with how this should look.

**The final calculate_damage formula should be dam * mod**

Answer (score 0):

I am on this course too, but I've done this question. This is what you should do:

```
dam = (((2 * l + 10) / 250) * (a / d) * b + 2) * calculate_modifier(STAB * Type * Critical * Other * Random)
```

If you try to calculate it inside the dam function, the autograder disqualifies you.

Answer (score 0):

You just return the `mod` value from the first function and pass it to second,
You don't have to pass 9 parameters to second function.

```
def calculate_modifier(s, t, c, o, r):
    mod = s * t * c * o * r
    return mod

def calculate_damage(l, a, d, b, mod):
    dam = (((2 * l + 10) / 250) * (a / d) * b + 2) * mod
    return dam

mod = calculate_modifier(s, t, c, o, r)
dam = calculate_damage(l, a, d, b, mod)
```

or you can return from both function and pass them to the third function to calculate the final value

```
def calculate_modifier(s, t, c, o, r):
    mod = s * t * c * o * r
    return mod

def calculate_damage(l, a, d, b, mod):
    dam = (((2 * l + 10) / 250) * (a / d) * b + 2)
    return dam

def calculate_total_damage(mod, dam):
    return dam * mod

mod = calculate_modifier(s, t, c, o, r)
dam = calculate_damage(l, a, d, b)
final = calculate_total_damage(mod, dam)
```